# Low power ripple pulse counter

Tags: avr, integrated-circuit, low-power, counter, pulse

I'm trying to find a **ripple/pulse/edge counter chip** that can record rising edges from a wind anemometer while my AVR sleeps. The signal is typically 0-50 Hz. I want to read it every 10 minutes, so it needs to be 14/15/16 bit or more.

I'm hoping to find a chip that can keep track of the number of rising edges at a lower power cost than waking up the AVR at each pulse.

**Does anyone have a suggestion for such a chip?** I'm obviously searching for the wrong keywords. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

I'd like the to read the data serially, if possible.

I found the DS2423 Maxim chip. It seems like a good fit, but it is discontinued: http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/comms/one-wire/DS2423.html

Comment: I think ANY CMOS counter would fill your needs, except maybe for the number of stages. A CD4060 has 14 stages. Not all are accessible from the outside, but you could feed it extra pulses until the unreachable stages overflow. But IMO Sehro suggestion is better, and even waking up each 5 ms might still yield very low current consumption.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I had a look at 4060 and it's alternatives. It's a good fit and I would have gone for it if it hadn't been for a scope change of the project (some other tasks also needed to be done, and a mcu could do both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty tall order- for what seems like a tiny market niche.

I suggest you consider using a microcontroller that has a counter that works in sleep mode (asynchronous with system clock). For example, Timer 1 on the PIC24FJ128.

Comment: I ended up using a attiny, counting pulses and outputting i2c. The power consumptions was low enough for my application :)

I also discovered that larger avr chips also have async timers, which can run while sleeping and trigger interrupts on compare overflow like the PIC you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Two 74HC4040 or CD4040B will get you 24 bits of count, and three 74HC165 will get you 24 bits of parallel-in serial-out shift, for a total of 5 MCU I/Os, or 4 if you invert one of the RESETs in hardware.

Comment: Might also need some sort of pulse shaping on the input, e.g. one gate of a 40106 or 4093, if the anemometer output doesn't always rise and fall sharply (say at very low wind speeds).

Comment: @nekomatic: Missed your comment earlier; sorry. The 4040 has a Schmitt trigger clock input.

Comment: I should have known that! It's a good choice then.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go really low power, something like [ABLIC S-35770](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ABLIC/S-35770E01I-K8T2U?qs=vLWxofP3U2yvSXNQEw14rA%3D%3D) may be suitable for you.